# Use join-table of many-to-many relationship as source for another relation

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities, `Project` and `Tag`, defined as below

```csharp
// Project.cs

namespace ProjectResume.Data.Entities
{
    public class Project
    {

        public Project()
        {
            this.Tags = new List<Tag>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("([a-z0-9\\-])+")]
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        [MaxLength(512)]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public string DetailedDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }

}
```

```csharp
// Tag.cs

namespace ProjectResume.Data.Entities
{
    public class Tag
    {
        public Tag()
        {
            this.Projects = new List<Project>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        [MaxLength(32)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("([a-z0-9\\-])+")]
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("#([a-fA-F0-9]{6}|[a-fA-F0-9]{3})")]
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```csharp
// DefaultDbContext.cs

namespace ProjectResume.Data
{
    public class DefaultDbContext : DbContext
    {
        // ...

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
                .WithMany(t => t.Projects);

        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to create a 3rd entity, `ProjectTagHighlight`, which should store one or more highlights per project per tag. I'd assume the table needs at least an `Id`, `ProjectId`, `TagId`, `Description`, but I'm unsure on how to set up this relation given the code I already have, given the fact that I don't specify a `ProjectTag` entity myself.

The goal is to be able to access data in two different ways, either

`Tag -> Project[] -> ProjectTagHighlight[]` or `Project -> Tag[] -> ProjectTagHighlight[]`

Comment: Given that ProjectTag is now a custom link, you'll can create an entity in your model for that, or in your Highlights table create a FK to both Project and Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used the third-part `ProjectTagHighlight`. You can access data as

```
ProjectTagHighlight -> Tag , ProjectTagHighlight -> Project
```

They form a many-to-many relationship through ProjectTagHighlight.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectTagHighlight>()
            .HasOne(x => x.project)
            .WithOne(y => y.projectTagHighlight)
            .HasForeignKey<ProjectTagHighlight>(f => f.ProjectId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectTagHighlight>()
            .HasOne(x => x.tag)
            .WithOne(y => y.projectTagHighlight)
            .HasForeignKey<ProjectTagHighlight>(f => f.TagId);
```

Comment: I don't think this is right, `y => y.projectTagHighlight` shouldn't be a `WithOne`, or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Because ProjectTagHighlight  has two foreign key, they can connect multiple Tags and Projects.